# Anti_join between df1 and df2 but how to change all mismatch in df2 to NA

Tags: r, rename, anti-join

Below are my two dataframes, df1 and df2

```
df1 <- data.frame(id=c("632592651","633322173","634703802","634927873","635812953","636004739","636101211","636157799","636263106","636752420"),text=c("asdf","cat","dog","mouse","elephant","goose","rat","mice","kitty","kitten"),response=c("y","y","y","n","n","y","y","n","n","y"))

id     text response
1  632592651     asdf        y
2  633322173      cat        y
3  634703802      dog        y
4  634927873    mouse        n
5  635812953 elephant        n
6  636004739    goose        y
7  636101211      rat        y
8  636157799     mice        n
9  636263106    kitty        n
10 636752420   kitten        y

df2 <- data.frame(id=c("632592651","633322173","634703802","634927873","635812953","636004739","636101211","636157799","636263106","636752420","636809222","2004722036","2004894388","2005045755","2005535472","2005630542","2005788781","2005809679","2005838317","2005866692"),
                  text=c("asdf_xyz","cat","dog","mouse","elephant","goose","rat","mice","kitty","kitten","tiger_xyz","lion","leopard","ostrich","kangaroo","platypus","fish","reptile","mammals","amphibians_xyz"),
                  volume=c("1234","432","324","333","2223","412346","7456","3456","2345","2345","6","345","23","2","4778","234","8675","3459","8","9"))

 id           text volume
1   632592651       asdf_xyz   1234
2   633322173            cat    432
3   634703802            dog    324
4   634927873          mouse    333
5   635812953       elephant   2223
6   636004739          goose 412346
7   636101211            rat   7456
8   636157799           mice   3456
9   636263106          kitty   2345
10  636752420         kitten   2345
11  636809222      tiger_xyz      6
12 2004722036           lion    345
13 2004894388        leopard     23
14 2005045755        ostrich      2
15 2005535472       kangaroo   4778
16 2005630542       platypus    234
17 2005788781           fish   8675
18 2005809679        reptile   3459
19 2005838317        mammals      8
20 2005866692 amphibians_xyz      9
```

How do I change the non-matching items from row id1:20 of df2 to NA (i.e. all of them as no matching with df1) and the column 'text' (i.e. asdf_xyz) of id1 to NA?

I have tried

```
library(dplyr)

df3 <- df2 %>%
  anti_join(df1, by=c("id"))

id           text volume
1   636809222      tiger_xyz      6
2  2004722036           lion    345
3  2004894388        leopard     23
4  2005045755        ostrich      2
5  2005535472       kangaroo   4778
6  2005630542       platypus    234
7  2005788781           fish   8675
8  2005809679        reptile   3459
9  2005838317        mammals      8
10 2005866692 amphibians_xyz      9

df3$id[df3$id != 0] <- NA
df3$text[df3$text != 0] <- NA
df3$volume[df3$volume != 0] <- NA
```

(Doing this one by one because I couldn't find solution how to change the entire value of the dataframe to NA)

```
id text volume
1  <NA> <NA>   <NA>
2  <NA> <NA>   <NA>
3  <NA> <NA>   <NA>
4  <NA> <NA>   <NA>
5  <NA> <NA>   <NA>
6  <NA> <NA>   <NA>
7  <NA> <NA>   <NA>
8  <NA> <NA>   <NA>
9  <NA> <NA>   <NA>
10 <NA> <NA>   <NA>
```

and df4 (solution from [How to return row values that match column 'id' in both df1 and df2 but not column 'text' and return NA to the mismatch in column 'text'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72781501/how-to-return-row-values-that-match-column-id-in-both-df1-and-df2-but-not-colu/72781808?noredirect=1#comment128555870_72781808))

```
inner_join(x = df1, 
           y = df2, 
           by = "id") %>%
  mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
  mutate(text = ifelse(test = text.x != text.y, 
                       yes = NA, 
                       no = text.x)) %>%
  select(id, text, response, volume)

id     text response volume
1  632592651     <NA>        y   1234
2  633322173      cat        y    432
3  634703802      dog        y    324
4  634927873    mouse        n    333
5  635812953 elephant        n   2223
6  636004739    goose        y 412346
7  636101211      rat        y   7456
8  636157799     mice        n   3456
9  636263106    kitty        n   2345
10 636752420   kitten        y   2345
```

but not sure how to replace df2 with df3 and df4. The desired output is shown below:

```
id           text volume
1   632592651       NA   1234
2   633322173            cat    432
3   634703802            dog    324
4   634927873          mouse    333
5   635812953       elephant   2223
6   636004739          goose 412346
7   636101211            rat   7456
8   636157799           mice   3456
9   636263106          kitty   2345
10  636752420         kitten   2345
11  NA               NA      NA
12  NA               NA      NA
13  NA               NA      NA
14  NA               NA      NA
15  NA               NA      NA
16  NA               NA      NA
17  NA               NA      NA
18  NA               NA      NA
19  NA               NA      NA
20  NA               NA      NA
```

Can someone help please?
If possible, may I also know if there's a manual approach to select subset of df2 based on df3$id and change all values to NA?

Part 2:

For the second part of my request, I would like to create another  dataframes from joined_df which appears only in df1 (call it found_in_df1). Example of output:

found_in_df1:

```
#           id     text volume
# 1: 632592651     <NA>   1234
# 2: 633322173      cat    432
# 3: 634703802      dog    324
# 4: 634927873    mouse    333
# 5: 635812953 elephant   2223
# 6: 636004739    goose 412346
# 7: 636101211      rat   7456
# 8: 636157799     mice   3456
# 9: 636263106    kitty   2345
#10: 636752420   kitten   2345
```

The solution is given in [How to return row values that match column 'id' in both df1 and df2 but not column 'text' and return NA to the mismatch in column 'text'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72781501/how-to-return-row-values-that-match-column-id-in-both-df1-and-df2-but-not-colu) but I'm looking for an alternative approach, i.e., is it possible to write a script to say retrieve from joined_df using df1 to give found_in_df1  since we have df1 and joined_df?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One potential solution for dealing with conflicts is to use the [powerjoin package](https://github.com/moodymudskipper/powerjoin), e.g.

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 <- data.frame(id=c("632592651","633322173","634703802","634927873","635812953","636004739","636101211","636157799","636263106","636752420"),
                  text=c("asdf","cat","dog","mouse","elephant","goose","rat","mice","kitty","kitten"),
                  response=c("y","y","y","n","n","y","y","n","n","y"))

df2 <- data.frame(id=c("632592651","633322173","634703802","634927873","635812953","636004739","636101211","636157799","636263106","636752420","636809222","2004722036","2004894388","2005045755","2005535472","2005630542","2005788781","2005809679","2005838317","2005866692"),
                  text=c("asdf_xyz","cat","dog","mouse","elephant","goose","rat","mice","kitty","kitten","tiger_xyz","lion","leopard","ostrich","kangaroo","platypus","fish","reptile","mammals","amphibians_xyz"),
                  volume=c(1234,432,324,333,2223,412346,7456,3456,2345,2345,6,345,23,2,4778,234,8675,3459,8,9))

expected_outcome <- data.frame(id = c("632592651","633322173","634703802","634927873","635812953","636004739","636101211","636157799","636263106","636752420",
                                      NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
                               text = c(NA, "cat", "dog", "mouse", "elephant", "goose", 
                                        "rat", "mice", "kitty", "kitten", 
                                        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
                               volume = c(1234, 432, 324, 333, 2223, 412346, 7456, 
                                          3456, 2345, 2345, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA))

library(powerjoin)
joined_df <- power_full_join(df1, df2, by = c("id"),
                             conflict = rw ~ ifelse(.x != .y,
                                                    NA_integer_, 
                                                    .x))

final_df <- joined_df %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ifelse(is.na(response), NA, .x))) %>%
  select(id, text, volume)
final_df
#>           id     text volume
#> 1  632592651     <NA>   1234
#> 2  633322173      cat    432
#> 3  634703802      dog    324
#> 4  634927873    mouse    333
#> 5  635812953 elephant   2223
#> 6  636004739    goose 412346
#> 7  636101211      rat   7456
#> 8  636157799     mice   3456
#> 9  636263106    kitty   2345
#> 10 636752420   kitten   2345
#> 11      <NA>     <NA>     NA
#> 12      <NA>     <NA>     NA
#> 13      <NA>     <NA>     NA
#> 14      <NA>     <NA>     NA
#> 15      <NA>     <NA>     NA
#> 16      <NA>     <NA>     NA
#> 17      <NA>     <NA>     NA
#> 18      <NA>     <NA>     NA
#> 19      <NA>     <NA>     NA
#> 20      <NA>     <NA>     NA

all_equal(final_df, expected_outcome)
#> [1] TRUE

# Part 2
found_in_df1 <- power_left_join(df1, df2, by = c("id"),
                                conflict = rw ~ ifelse(.x != .y,
                                                       NA_integer_, 
                                                       .x)) %>%
  select(id, text, volume)
found_in_df1
#>           id     text volume
#> 1  632592651     <NA>   1234
#> 2  633322173      cat    432
#> 3  634703802      dog    324
#> 4  634927873    mouse    333
#> 5  635812953 elephant   2223
#> 6  636004739    goose 412346
#> 7  636101211      rat   7456
#> 8  636157799     mice   3456
#> 9  636263106    kitty   2345
#> 10 636752420   kitten   2345
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

### Edit

Per the comment below from the creator of the powerjoin package (Mr. Mudskipper): these operations are vectorised, so you don't need to perform the command 'rowwise', i.e. you can remove "rw" to simplify and gain performance. There is no practical difference between including and excluding "rw" with df1 and df2, but if we use larger dataframes you can see a clear increase in performance, e.g.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(powerjoin)

# define functions
power_full_join_func_rowwise <- function(df1, df2) {
  joined_df <- power_full_join(df1, df2, by = c("id"),
                               conflict = rw ~ ifelse(.x != .y,
                                                      NA_integer_, 
                                                      .x))
  
  final_df <- joined_df %>%
    mutate(across(everything(), ~ifelse(is.na(response), NA, .x))) %>%
    select(id, text, volume)
  return(final_df)
}

power_full_join_func_not_rowwise <- function(df1, df2) {
  joined_df <- power_full_join(df1, df2, by = c("id"),
                               conflict = ~ifelse(.x != .y,
                                                      NA_integer_, 
                                                      .x))
  
  final_df <- joined_df %>%
    mutate(across(everything(), ~ifelse(is.na(response), NA, .x))) %>%
    select(id, text, volume)
  return(final_df)
}

library(microbenchmark)
library(purrr)
library(ggplot2)

# make larger dfs (copy df1 and df2 X100)
df3 <- map_dfr(seq_len(100), ~ df1)
df4 <- map_dfr(seq_len(100), ~ df2)

# benchmark performance on the larger dataframes
res <- microbenchmark(power_full_join_func_rowwise(df3, df4),
                      power_full_join_func_not_rowwise(df3, df4))
res
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>                                        expr       min        lq      mean
#>      power_full_join_func_rowwise(df3, df4) 397.32661 426.08117 449.88787
#>  power_full_join_func_not_rowwise(df3, df4)  71.85757  77.25344  90.36191
#>     median        uq      max neval cld
#>  446.41715 472.47817 587.3301   100   b
#>   81.18239  93.95103 191.1248   100  a
autoplot(res)
#> Coordinate system already present. Adding new coordinate system, which will replace the existing one.
```

[image]

```r
# Is the result the same?
all_equal(power_full_join_func_rowwise(df3, df4),
          power_full_join_func_not_rowwise(df3, df4))
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks @jared_mamrot. I couldn't understand some of the syntax. Still a R beginner. Can you kindly explain what these two syntaxes are doing? 
conflict = rw ~ ifelse(.x != .y, NA_integer_, .x)) and mutate(across(everything(), ~ifelse(is.na(response), NA, .x)))

Comment: Yes, absolutely, the syntax is explained further in the docs for [powerjoin](https://github.com/moodymudskipper/powerjoin) and for [dplyr::across()](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html). `conflict = rw ~ ifelse(.x != .y, NA_integer_, .x))` => for each row (rw = "row wise") if text from df1 doesn't equal the text from df2 (i.e. there is a conflict) write "NA", otherwise use the 'non-conflicting' value. `mutate(across(everything(), ~ifelse(is.na(response), NA, .x)))` => for every row, if response is NA make the value for each column NA, otherwise don't change the value. Make sense?

Comment: There are way better explanations in the documentation for each of these packages; probably better to click on the links and go through the examples to understand what is going on

Comment: Thanks @jared_mamrot! If it's alright with you (will edit the question to add the additional request), can you also include solution to create another 2 dataframes from joined_df which 1) appears only in df1, 2) appears in both df1 and df2. I apologise in advance for asking this as I have hard time figuring out how to do this after going through so many posts :).

Comment: Totally fine; updated my answer to hopefully address your two questions. Please feel free to ask if you want further clarification.

Comment: Thanks again @jared_mamrot. Actually want something slightly different. Sorry that I didn't clarify enough but hopefully it is now. See the edited question "Part 2".

Comment: Oh! I'm sorry - I didn't understand, even though you explained it clearly. I've updated my answer with a potential solution for "Part 2" as well (underneath "Part 1"). If this doesn't solve your problem, please let me know and I will help you troubleshoot.

Comment: Thanks @jared_mamrot! I played with your solution, modified slightly to see if I arrive with the same output and it did. First the solution is exactly the same as doing `pij_df <- power_inner_join(df1, df2, by = c("id"), conflict = rw ~ ifelse(.x != .y, NA_integer_, .x))` which you would have noticed. Then instead of power_left_join df1 and df2, I did `filter <- power_left_join(df1, final_df, by=c("id"), conflict = rw ~ ifelse(.x != .y, NA_integer_, .x))` which arrives at the same output! I think these alternatives are great for cross-checking. Thanks again!

Comment: Since all operations on the res are vectorized we might remove the `rw` to simplify and gain performance

Comment: Thanks @moodymudskipper, I didn't realise that was the case but it makes sense. I updated my answer to illustrate your point (hopefully it's clear).

Comment: Thanks, I think the documentation of powerjoin might be improved to make this clearer. This is very similar to using `rowwise()` before `mutate()` with dplyr

Answer (score 1):

*data.table* version using an `!antijoin`, and overwriting `:=` all columns/rows returned in `df2` with an `NA` (recycled list `.(NA)` to all columns).
Then looping over all the common variables and overwriting any values which don't match by `id`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)

df2[!df1, on=.(id), names(df2) := .(NA)]
idvars <- "id"
compvars <- setdiff(intersect(names(df1), names(df2)), idvars)
for (i in compvars) {
    df2[!df1, on=c(idvars,i), (i) := NA]
}

#           id     text volume
# 1: 632592651     <NA>   1234
# 2: 633322173      cat    432
# 3: 634703802      dog    324
# 4: 634927873    mouse    333
# 5: 635812953 elephant   2223
# 6: 636004739    goose 412346
# 7: 636101211      rat   7456
# 8: 636157799     mice   3456
# 9: 636263106    kitty   2345
#10: 636752420   kitten   2345
#11:      <NA>     <NA>   <NA>
#12:      <NA>     <NA>   <NA>
#13:      <NA>     <NA>   <NA>
#14:      <NA>     <NA>   <NA>
#15:      <NA>     <NA>   <NA>
#16:      <NA>     <NA>   <NA>
#17:      <NA>     <NA>   <NA>
#18:      <NA>     <NA>   <NA>
#19:      <NA>     <NA>   <NA>
#20:      <NA>     <NA>   <NA>
```

Comment: This is (obviously) a way more straightforward approach, but I believe OP wants the text in row 1 ("asdf_xyz") to be NA, as there is a conflict for that id between the two dataframes ("asdf" vs "asdf_xyz"). Do you know a way to do that with data.table?

Comment: @jared_mamrot - updated to take into account the extra steps.

Comment: Thanks @thelatemail for providing an alternative solution. The team I work with
 like to stick with dplyr solution unfortunately.